# Identify a value change of p:selectOneMenu in viewAction

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a `<p:selectOneMenu>` on a master page template holding a list of currencies. I have also a [`<p:slider>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/slider.jsf) to search between a range of prices of different products.

When a `<p:commandButton>` is pressed after setting a range, the page is redirected to another page which displays a list of products according the the range.

After this, if an attempt is made to change the currency as said above, I want to redirect to the home page.

The following XHTML and corresponding managed bean to display a list of products according the the selected range in `<p:slider>`.

```
<ui:define name="metaData">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="minPrice" value="#{productPriceManagedBean.minPrice}" maxlength="20"/>
        <f:viewParam name="maxPrice" value="#{productPriceManagedBean.maxPrice}" maxlength="20"/>
        <f:viewAction action="#{productPriceManagedBean.viewAction}"/>
    </f:metadata>
</ui:define>
```

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public final class ProductPriceManagedBean implements Serializable
{
    private BigDecimal minPrice; //Getter and setter.
    private BigDecimal maxPrice; //Getter and setter.
    private boolean valueChanged;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ProductPriceManagedBean() {}     

    //This method is called, when a currency held by <p:selectOneMenu> is changed.
    public void currencyChanged(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws IOException {
        this.valueChanged=true;
    }

    public void viewAction()
    {            
        if(valueChanged) //valueChange is always false here.
        {
            ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();  
            context.redirect(context.getRequestContextPath()+"/public_resources/Product.jsf");
        }
    }
}
```

When a currency is changed in `<p:selectOneMenu>` on the master template, the `currencyChanged()` method is called setting the value of `valueChanged` to true but it is not available in the `viewAction()` method.

<s>It appears that the `viewAction()` method is invoked fairly early before the `currencyChanged()` method is invoked.</s>

What is the way to get around this situation?

Anyway I need to redirect to the home page, if a currency is changed **on the master page template** after a list of products according the range slider has been displayed.

---

<sub>I don't show the XHTML code superfluously here.</sub>

<sub>It is just like `<p:ajax listener="#{productPriceManagedBean.currencyChanged}"/>` inside `<p:selectOneMenu>`.</sub>

Comment: When is `viewAction()` getting called ? When you change the view, the values in view scoped beans will be reset. Why don't you simply add your redirect method in the currency change event listener ? Maybe `valueChanged` should be in a session scoped bean.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to consider another thing which is not covered in this question. The page is already redirected (from another bean), when a currency is changed in `<p:selectOneMenu>` (it is redirected from the action method of `<p:remoteCommand>` which is bound/mapped to the `onchange` event of `<p:selectOneMenu>` ). So this bean `ProductPriceManagedBean` reconstructed all over again. I'm now redirecting from that (another) bean based on an appropriate conditional check that works harmlessly. (If the page had not been redirected from that bean then, this method would have worked as it is).